# Converting a uint8_t array to an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

How can I affect  a `uint8_t` array (see `decryptedBuffer` below) to an `NSString`?

```
uint8_t *decryptedBuffer;

NSString *cle2=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:decryptedBuffer];

NSString *str2=[player.name AES256DecryptWithKey:cle2]; 
NSLog(str2);


free(plainBuffer);
free(cipherBuffer);
free(decryptedBuffer);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Do you want a string with the contents of `decrytpedBuffer`, or do you want a string representation of an integer?  I'm guessing the former, in which case you should explain what's going wrong currently and anything worth knowing about `decryptedBuffer` (e.g., is it null-terminated, do you know the length, etc.).

Comment: i want the same value in decryptedBuffer  affected in str2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`uint8_t *` is just a byte string which is compatible with `char *`, so you should just be able to pass the casted pointer to `stringWithUTF8String`, assuming the decrypted string is UTF-8 and it is NULL terminated:

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)decryptedBuffer];
```

If the data is not NULL terminated, you can use this:

```
NSString *s = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:decryptedBuffer
                                 length:length_of_buffer
                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Comment: I notice you haven't accepted any of your previous answers. If this answer helps you, click the arrow on the left to accept it.

Comment: How about to NSNumber?

Answer (score -1):

decryptedBuffer is an int (uint8_t), NSString stringWithUTF8String only works on strings, not ints. I think I found what you need: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2004/Apr/msg01437.html

That person used this syntax:

```
    NSString *theDigitsIWant = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:x] stringValue];
```

So you should do this:

```
    NSString *cle2 = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:decryptedBuffer] stringValue];
```

Comment: but haw i can convert my bro?

Comment: thx bro ,but have you solution to affected the value of uintf_8 in NSString?

Comment: for exemple the value of decryptedBuffer is 0123456789012345678901234567890123401234567rpol and i want cle2 have this value from decryptedBuffer

Comment: oh rite i get what you mean... i thought you wanted to convert a single uint8_t to a string, lol

Comment: xfbs,my bro have u solution to insert the value in my cle2